# How to do PHP insert using SQL 'Default' keyword for auto incremented primary key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi, i'm trying to do a PHP insert using PDO:

```
$sqlStr = "INSERT INTO agents VALUES (:id,:sport, :firmName, :agentLastName, :agentFirsttName, :address1, :address2, :suite, :city, :stateProv, :zipcode, :country, :phone, :fax, :email, :website, :comment, :lastUpdated)";
```

I want to bind the MySQL 'Default' keyword to my id because my id is auto incremented. But, 'Default' is already a keyword in PHP.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question exactly, but if you pass in NULL as the auto-incrementing field it will work as expected.

Comment: I don't understand. Auto-increment fields are numeric and you are trying to add some text to that field. In other words - it ain't going to work no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix: pass `NULL` for the ID.

The good fix: list all fields in the statement that should receive a value and omit the id field. (This way you can also use the auto update capabilities of a TIMESTAMP column)